# PowerShell $Profile add $psISE.CurrentFile.Editor.ToggleOutliningExpansion() to collapse all #regions on open

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise, powershell-5.0

I would like to have all #regions closed on open of a script with #regions. My ultimate goal...
in $Profile

1. Open PowerShell ISE in Administrator mode
2. Open a .PS1 file
3. have all collapsible #regions collapsed when the script opens.* $psISE.CurrentFile.Editor.ToggleOutliningExpansion()

Comment: This works! if you click on .PS1 and open it the command fails, but if you open PowerShell then open a file it is 100% collapsed! THANKS. Is there a way to open the .PS1 file collapsed without opening PowerShell first?

Comment: it works if you open PS first then File>Open and choose file. If you choose a .PS1 file rt click open it does not work. (I did close the ISE). You gave me what I asked for. I just didn't 'ask for' what I wanted! I can work with this if there is not a way to rt click .PS1 script open collapsed

Comment: YUP! that did it!---thanks in less than hr you have given two fantastic answers. The one I asked for and the one I needed... Thanks PetSerAI